# Use inheritance vs __init__(self, superclass)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am doubting my OOP approach and I would like your advice.
I've read enough about inheritance, but it seems this is not what I am looking for. The reason for this is rather simple - I have a lot of arguments in the "Parent" class and I don't want to retype them every time I call a "Child" class. Such as:

```
class Parent:
   def __init__(self, wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F):
      self.wl = wl
      self.wf = wf
      ....
      self.F = F

class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self, wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F):
       super().__init__( wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F)
   
   def foo(self):
      return self.wl * self.wf
```

And then initializing both classes should look like this:

```
par = Parent(wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F)
kid = Child(wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F)
```

I personally don't like to pass so many args to the `Child` class, because I would use only 2 arguments `wl, wf` there, while others would just silently pass through with no reason.

That's why instead of normal inheritance I use the following method:

```
class Parent:
   def __init__(self, wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F):
      self.wl = wl
      self.wf = wf
      ....
      self.F = F

class Child():
   def __init__(self, class):
       self.wl = class.wl
       self.wf = class.wl

   
   def foo(self):
      return self.wl * self.wf
```

And then initialization is easier:

```
par = Parent(wl, wf, Lx, Ly, num, w0, F)
kid = Child(par)
```

But honestly saying, I don't know if it's the best approach. Is there a method to have inheritance but to pass just a few arguments from a parent to a child?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your child class's `__init__()` can have as many or as few parameters as it wants.  But when it calls the inherited `__init__()`, it would have to somehow provide values for all of the parameters that the parent class wants - either defaults, or calculated from the child parameters.  If the parent parameters *can't* be meaningfully set by the child, then the two classes probably shouldn't be related by inheritance at all.

Comment: You want inheritance when you want to use a `Child` where a `Parent` is expected—perhaps in the expression `p.F`.  In that case you **do** need all the constructor arguments in order to have that value available.

Comment: Thank you jasonharper and DavisHerring for your answers.  Then I suppose I chose a good approach!